# When and how does gradle resolve its dependencies?

Tags: ant, gradle, ivy, dependency-management

I'm trying to re-write our build to Gradle, but we want to keep the dependency management in Ivy, for internal reasons.

So while trying to do that, I'm having several questions regarding the way gradle handles its dependencies:

1. When does gradle resolve dependencies (without Ivy or anything)?
2. When adding IvySettings and ivy.xml, do I need to call something similar to ant's ivy:resolve or ivy:configure, or does Gradle take care of that? If so, when and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to (2), I managed to get gradle to read an ivy.xml file, and resolve the dependencies from there.

Gradle doesn't take care of that naturally, but using code from [this](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-197) issue, with a few tweaks, managed to get dependencies with gradle.

further more, there is a [IvyXML](http://admc.com/projectdocs/gradle-ivyxml-plugin/readme.html) plugin for gradle, with claims it can take care of most of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle resolves dependencies (more precisely configurations) on first use (typically by a task). Gradle doesn't read ivysettings or ivy.xml. (It does read ivy.xml files in the repository.) All information about dependency resolution is configured in Gradle build script(s).

Comment: Can you give me an example of the first use? I mean, it's not the Task that uses the dependencies, but the java class

Comment: Also, what do you mean "Gradle doesn't read ivysettings or ivy.xml"? I saw here: "https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-197" that you can interface with Ivy. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Not sure what example you are looking for. Dependency resolution is automatic, and there is nothing to do in the code. Just iterate over the `Configuration`, and it will give you all artifacts. For more information, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the examples in the `gradle-all` distribution. GRADLE-197 is unresolved, and will likely never get resolved. Gradle interfaces with *Ivy repositories*, not with the Ivy library.